# JUNG - best layouts for displaying large graphs (~1000 nodes)

Tags: java, graph, jung, yfiles

I want to migrate from YFiles to Jung. When it comes to small graphs, the display is almost similar with YFiles. But for large graphs, I didn't find any layout to satisfy my expectations. Here is a graph with 1000 elements that YFiles seems to display very well:
[YFiles Graph Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4UsN.png)

In Jung, there are inconsistent distances between sub-graphs, like in this picture:

[JUNG Graph Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdz2Z.png)

For JUNG I used a SparseMultigraph with a FRLayout with the following attributes:

```
FRLayout<GraphNode, GraphLink> layout = new FRLayout<>(graph);
layout.setMaxIterations(100);
layout.setAttractionMultiplier(0.2); // default 0.75
layout.setRepulsionMultiplier(0.3); // default 0.75
```

I played a lot with the number of iterations, attraction multiplier and repulsion multiplier but this is the best combination that I've found.

Is there a better suitable layout/graph for displaying such a graph in order to obtain something similar with what YFiles displays?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very specific outcome that you want from your layout, so probably your best bet is going to be to implement your own layout algorithm.  The layouts that JUNG provides are intended to be fairly generic and work reasonably well for a wide variety of graphs; they're not expected to do precisely what you would want for any particular graph.

One option that you would have, if you can find out what algorithm YFiles is using, would be to simply re-implement their algorithm.

However, in this case, since your graph appears to be an aggregation of a number of independent isolated components of exactly the same size and topology, I would suggest creating a specialized implementation laying the graph out deterministically.  You could use `WeakComponentClusterer` to identify the components, use a simple formula to figure out where the relative positions should be for each element of a component, and then lay out each component.

`StaticLayout` would be useful for the deterministic approach.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it could very well be that we layout components separately to avoid this exact sort of problem. I guess JUNG might require that step to be explicit.